# Update SQL query for HTML table Python

Tags: python, html, sql

I have the following code in my Python project:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Card Number</th>
    <th>Card Name</th>
    <th>Card Rarity</th>
    <th>Card Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  {% for card in card_data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{card.card_prefix}}</td>
    <td>{{card.card_name}}</td>
    <td>{{card.card_rarity}}</td>
    <td>{{card.card_quantity}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Is there a way to update the quantity to -1 or +1 on a button that only updates one row of the SQL database?

The current code in my main page is:

```
@app.route('/lob')
def lob():
    session.clear()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    current_set = 'LOB'

    session['set_selected'] = True
    session['current_set'] = current_set

    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card_list WHERE card_set =%s", [current_set])
    card_data = cur.fetchall()

    if result > 0:

        return render_template('/Booster Packs/lob.html', card_data=card_data)

    else:
        flash('Set Not Found!', 'danger')
        return render_template('/Booster Packs/lob.html')
```

I can update the question with more information if needed, I'm just not sure how to go about how to select the value to update given the table.

Sorry for the bad English, it is not my first language.

Comment: In this whole code, there is no updating of the database. You are just using sql to read from the database, python, to send the data to the webpage, javascript to display the data. I do not see any update. What do you want to update to -1 or 1?

Comment: @Onyambu I didn't include any updates as I didn't know how to specify what to update (didn't know how to get a specific table row data)

Comment: What row do you want to specify? Does the user tell you of the row? Like does your webpage collect the information from the user?? How do you know the row that you want to update?. Also, what exactly iin the row do you want to change?

Comment: Notice that you are fetching all the rows. So you must specify which row you want to update, and the condition of updating.

Comment: @Onyambu so the rows would be displayed in a table (shown in the first piece of code) and I would want to update the card_quantity of a single row in that displayed table.

Comment: Ask yourself this. Do you want to permanently change the data? Then update the fb. Do you want to change it during visualization? The update the javascript code. Use an ifelse statement. Ofcourse you need a condition. You have not stated  when it should be 1 and when it should be -1